# MEMORY in buffering txt

Tags: excel, vb6, vba

```
Sub DUE()

    Dim strBuffer As String
    Dim strContents() As String
    Dim I As Long

    ReDim strContents(0)
    Erase strContents()

    Close #1
    Open "C:\TEST\28-06-2013.TXT" For Input As #1
    strBuffer = Input(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1

    strContents = Split(strBuffer, vbCrLf)

    For I = LBound(strContents) To UBound(strContents)
        'Debug.Print strContents(I)
    Next I

End Sub
```

Problem out of Memory!!!!

When buffering the txt file. Is approx 256 mb 1.500.xxx lines. Each line have a fixed lenght 132.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use `Line Input` instead:

```
Sub DUE()
    Dim I As Long
    Dim strContents() As String
    Open "C:\TEST\28-06-2013.TXT" For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Redim Preserve strContents(i)
            Line Input #1, strContents(i)
            'Debug.Print strContents(i)
            I = I + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Then you can access each line from `strContents`.

Also worth noting:

```
ReDim strContents(0)
Erase strContents()
```

That isn't so proper.  Use my line instead:

```
Dim strContents() As String
```

EDIT:

Or better yet, do what you need to do on each line, and do not bother storing it inside `strContents`, like so:

```
Sub DUE()
    Dim S As String
    Open "C:\TEST\28-06-2013.TXT" For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, S
            'Debug.Print S
        Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: @SalvatoreImparato I updated my answer.  Use the second method.